# Array of async tasks. Can I attach metadata to each task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have some users. Each user has a List of Products. Each user is stored in blob storage with their products so I want to retrieve them in parallel which I can do fine.

The problem is that when each set of products are returned I don't know which user they relate to.

**Code:**

```
var tasks = users.Select(u => this.repository.GetProducts(u.UserName)).ToList();
var producstByUser = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach(List<Product> products in productsByUser)
{
    //how do I know which user each set of products are for??
}
```

Is there a way I can attach some metadata to the task call or something? Maybe I am going about this totally the wrong way?

Comment: Looks like all of those products are for a particular user, considering you are passing in a user name as an argument.  Something I'm missing?

Comment: Return a Tuple<string,List<Product>> with the name and products instead of just `List<Product>`. Tasks are about asynchronous execution, not transferring data.

Comment: `Task` is not magic; it's a type just like any other type. So you associate data just like you would with any other type: wrapping it in your own type, associated arrays, connected properties, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are doing this wrong. The point of async await is to maintain simple control flow, whilst running your code asynchronously.

```
var tasks = users.Select(async user =>
{
    var products = await this.repository.GetProducts(user.UserName);
    return new { user, products };
});
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var resultsAsDictionary = results(x => x.user, x => x.products);
```

Comment: The OP's problem was *not* how to *sequentially* execute each request in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then it's a good thing this doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy the OP mentioned *blob* storage. Executing multiple concurrent GET requests isn't a problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't say it would be.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so what is your problem? This code does multiple GETs. I still don't understand how running `users.Select(u => this.repository.GetProducts(u.UserName)).ToList()` does anything differently.

Comment: `users.Select(u => this.repository.GetProducts(u.UserName)).ToList()` will also sequentially create asynchronous GET operations.

Comment: The two cases still aren't the same. The OP's code will collect all results before proceeding with local processing. This is similar to the reduce phase of the MapReduce algorithm. There *are* things that have to be done after all results are collected, eg. calculating statistics to find the top user. This code on the other hand will process each individual result. In any case, the OP asked how to return the input together with the request's output, which isn't shown by this answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to run the requests to my repository in parallel however. You are awaiting each request to the repository. Although this is asynchronous etc with leaving my thread free it is running each request sequentially

Comment: @BritishDeveloper the action of creating the requests is of course done sequentially. That is a given on a single network card (think about it). Each request should be in flight in parallel. However I was informed you are using a REST api. By default .net limits the number of concurrent http requests per host. You should look at the appropriate config to ease that restriction. This code us correct for your usage.

Comment: @BritishDeveloper it seems like you are after a solution that uses parallel processing (threads). I assure you that none of the other solutions uses threads, nor should you be using threads for IO. You should read Stephen Cleary's blog there is no thread.

Comment: Sorry, I apologise. I have run some test as I was convinced that due to the await in your selector function you would be awaiting on each selection and not running in parallel. You are however selecting a list of tasks to be run NOT the results of the task. The Tasks only execute when you call Task.WhenAll

Answer (score 3):

Create an anonymous type/named type.

```
var items = users.Select(u => new
{
    User = u,
    ProductsTask = this.repository.GetProducts(u.UserName)
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(x => x.ProductsTask));
//Ignore the return value of `WhenAll` and just use the `items` collection
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var user = item.User;
    List<Product> products = item.ProductsTask.Result;
    //Accessing Task.Result is fine here, we know task already completed.

}
```

Comment: This works but you (and future readers) may incorrectly assume putting an await before the this.repository.GetProducts and make the selector method async means it will make the calls sequential but they wont. I thought that too to begin with FYI. Thanks again for your correct answer but it isn't the best here

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
var tasks = users.Select(u => 
     this.repository
         .GetProducts(u.UserName)
         .ContinueWith(products=>Tuple.Create(u, products.Result.ToList())));
var producstByUser = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach(Tuple<User, List<Product>> products in productsByUser)
{
    //products.Item1 is the user
    //products.Item2 are the products for the user
}
```

Comment: The query provider is highly unlikely going to be able to support those operations.

Comment: @Servy the OP mentioned blob storage. It's probably a request to a cloud provider which *does* support such access